# Azure Storage Account gets created without "blob.core.windows.net" endpoint

Tags: azure, command-line-interface, azure-storage

I have an `az cli` script to create resources for our application and its data, and we regularly use it to tear down and rebuild our dev environment.
Recently part of this stopped working, even though we did not change the script. Specifically we do:

```
az storage account create -g <my-rg-name> --name <my-storage-account-name> --sku Standard_RAGRS --kind StorageV2 --hns --min-tls-version TLS1_2 --access-tier Hot
```

followed by

```
az storage container create --auth-mode login -g <my-rg-name> --account-name <my-storage-account-name> --name documents --public-access off
```

The last time I ran it successfully was 15th September. Next time I tried was 27th September, and that failed, and it has continued to fail since.

The error message when creating the storage container includes this:

```
azure.common.AzureException: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='<my-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net', port=443):
 Max retries exceeded with url: /documents?restype=container (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x04D38928>:
 Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))
```

So here's interesting - it was trying `<my-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net` but actually if I look at the endpoints on the newly created storage account they are:

```
 "primaryEndpoints": {
    "blob": "https://<my-account-name>.z47.blob.storage.azure.net/",
    "dfs": "https://<my-account-name>.z47.dfs.storage.azure.net/",
    "file": "https://<my-account-name>.z47.file.storage.azure.net/",
    "internetEndpoints": null,
    "microsoftEndpoints": null,
    "queue": "https://<my-account-name>.z47.queue.storage.azure.net/",
    "table": "https://<my-account-name>.z47.table.storage.azure.net/",
    "web": "https://<my-account-name>.z47.web.storage.azure.net/"
  },
```

so where we were expecting "xxx.blob.core.windows.net", we're getting "xxx.z47.blob.storage.azure.net".
That's *potentially* fine I guess we could query for that name, and use it - but I can't easily fix az cli, and the fact that they have a hard expectation that the blob.core.windows.net domain name exists makes me think lots of other things that try to consume it will be broken (my ADF pipelines that consume the storage account definitely are - but *maybe* I'd fix them to cope with the different url if that's all it is - but I suspect this is not normal and want to understand why).

I've confirmed it is not az cli specific - if I create a storage account in the portal we still get the non-standard endpoints. So it is something in our Subscription/resource group, but I just have no idea why it is behaving like this or what to do about it.
Certainly Microsoft's documentation sets a clear expectation that we'll get a blob.core.windows.net endpoint (e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-overview).

Does anyone know what would cause Azure to behave this way?

Comment: @GauravMantri same result through the portal. This in my corporate client's subscription. If I go to a personal subscription and create a new RG and storage account I get the normal behaviour.

Comment: az cli version is 2.28.0. I updated it on Monday to see if that was the issue!

Comment: I would recommend reaching out to Azure Support in this case. Usually you see things like `z47` get embedded in the endpoint only for static website endpoint.

Answer (score -1):

It turns out that the reason for getting those curious-looking endpoints is that we have recently had a private preview feature turned on called "Partitioned DNS". This feature allows us to go beyond the normal limit of 250 storage account per subscription per region.

Support in the SDKs is not complete. Among those not supported at the present time is AZ CLI. Hence the issues that we have seen (specifically - could not create storage container, and `az storage account show-connection-string` returns a lie). JS and Powershell are also not supported.

The headline at the moment is that we can work around *most* of these things by using recent SDKs and the correct connection string. But I was not able to get Azure Storage Events to work at all - and that's unfortunate because that's quite a fundamental part of our application.

#### Details

Here are some details of what we've found, and what we've done about it.

- **az CLI** - can't fix, but can do things differently

  - create containers using an arm template - this is the approach we have taken
  - azcopy includes container creation capability - I didn't explore that option
  - do everything in the portal
- **.NET** - changed connection string to specify endpoint explicitly - everything seems to work
- **Python** - changed connection string specify endpoint explicitly - everything seems to work
- **Devops Pipelines (AzureFileCopy@3)** - works if you specify 'destType:blob' command line parameter
- **Azure Data Factory**:

  - Can make pipelines involving Copy tasks with Azure Storage as the source and/or sink work by giving the linked service the full URL for dfs endpoint.
  - **Can't make storage event triggers work under any circumstances**

To try to resolve the storage event triggers issue, I have tried creating the storage events from the Azure Storage side, instead of getting ADF to do it (thinking maybe ADF had the core.windows.net assumption, and if I created the pieces separately I could join them up), but alas, no luck. I cannot find a way of creating Azure Storage Events with these partitioned DNS endpoints.
For now, we are implementing a temporary workaround in ADF that is on a schedule trigger, and polls for files in Azure Storage (and even that is not easy - there is no ADF block that lists blobs, we had to write an Azure Function). Yuck. Hoping Microsoft will close that gap soon.

Answer (score -2):

As suggested by @Gaurav Mantri Please submit a ticket to azure support team.

Go to azure portal>> help+support >>click on create new support ticket and fill the required details and submit the ticket

Comment: Gaurav's comment is sufficient. This isn't an answer, and shouldn't be posted as such.

Comment: Technical support tickets aren't available for all